# Novel where a daughter remembers a previous life and draws pictures of it

Tags: story-identification, novel

I would like to find a novel whose review I read 20 or 30 years ago and would have liked to read at the time.

A man has a pre-school aged daughter who begins to draw fantastic landscapes which she describes as pictures of where she was before she came there. The father goes from thinking they are cute, to thinking there is something wrong with the girl, to taking her claim seriously, (I believe).

That is all I remember for sure.  I think the book probably appeared in the early-mid 90's and may have been a first novel.   I probably read the review in the NY Times, but it may have been in the Wall Street Journal, at any rate, it got mainstream reviews.

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard to find, but... Well. While looking for your book, I did find a list of [helpful hints](https://www.nypl.org/blog/2017/11/22/finding-book-forgotten-title?page=6) from the New York Public Library. And a serious website on [drawings](https://psi-encyclopedia.spr.ac.uk/articles/past-life-memories-illustrated), possibly of past lives, made by children.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Yes-My-Darling-Daughter-Novel-ebook/dp/B003CSOSQO seems too new.

Comment: It was definitely a father and daughter, I can't remember if the mother was still around or not.